# mongodb map reduce on multicore server

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, parallel-processing, mapreduce, nodes

I have a mongodb with thousands of records holding very long vectors. 
I am looking for correlations between an input vector with my MDB data set using a certain algorithm.

psudo code:

```
function find_best_correlation(input_vector)
    max_correlation = 0
    return_vector = []
    foreach reference_vector in dataset:
        if calculateCorrelation(input_vector,reference_vector) > max_correlation then:
            return_vector = reference_vector
    return return_vector
```

This is a very good candidate for map-reduce pattern as I don't care for the order the calculations are run in.

The issue is that my database is on one node.
I would like to run many mappings simultaneously (I have an 8 core machine)

From what I understand, MongoDb only uses one thread of execution per node - in practice I am running my data set serially.
Is this correct?

If so can I configure the number of processes/threads per map-reduce run? 
If I manage multiple threads running map-reduce in parallel and then aggregate the results will I have substantial performance increase (Has anybody tried)?
If not - can i have multiple replications of my DB on the same node and "trick" mongoDb to run on 2 replications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Map reduce in MongoDB uses Spidermonkey, a single-threaded Javascript engine, so it is not possible to configure multiple processes (and there are no "tricks").  There is a JIRA ticket to use a multi-threaded JS engine, which you can follow here:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2407

If possible, I would consider looking into the new aggregation framework (available in MongoDB version 2.2), which is written in C++ instead of Javascript and may offer performance improvements:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks but still not clear if I can have several replications on the same machine to work agains.

Comment: Running multiple MongoD instances on a single node is not recommended. The processes can compete for resources like RAM, which should be avoided. Another possible solution to avoid single-threaded MR may be the MongoDB Hadoop connector, which separates data storage from processing: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop

Comment: But to provide a more complete answer, there is a single JS engine per process, so in theory (although not recommended), it should be possible to run multiple MR jobs on a single node if there are multiple MongoDs.  A better solution is to run MR jobs in parallel on different shards.

Comment: Update: MongoDB uses V8 as of version 2.3.1, issue SERVER-2407 is closed. However, I'm not aware how this has affected concurrency of M/R jobs.

Comment: As of mongo 2.6, with a write and map-reduce heavy mongo instance, I still see only one CPU busy.