# Map-Reduce performance in MongoDb 2.2, 2.4, and 2.6

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I've found this discussion: [MongoDB: Terrible MapReduce Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947889/mongodb-terrible-mapreduce-performance). Basically it says try to avoid Mongo's MR queries as it single-threaded and not supposed to be for real-time at all. 2 years has passed, and I wonder what has been changed since the time. Now we have MongoDb 2.2. I heard MRs are now multi-threaded. Please share your ideas over MR usage for real-time requests like fetching data for web application frequent http requests. Is it able to effectively use indexes?

Comment: Meybe aggregation framework will be change something, right now map reduce is dam slow

Comment: Any idea why is that? Is it still single-threaded?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9434093/979474   or   http://stackoverflow.com/a/11749738/979474

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is the current state of functionality for Map/Reduce in MongoDB

1) Most of the performance limitations for Map/Reduce still remain in MongoDB version 2.2.  The Map/Reduce engine still requires that every record get converted from BSON to JSON, the actual calculations are performed using the embedded JavaScript engine (which is slow), and there still is a single global JavaScript lock, which only allows a single JavaScript thread to run at a single time.

There have been some incremental improvements to Map/Reduce for sharded clusters.  Most notably, the final Reduce operation is now distributed across multiple shards, and the output is also sharded in parallel.

I would not recommend Map/Reduce for real-time aggregation in MongoDB version 2.2

2) Starting with MongoDB 2.2, there is now a new Aggregation Framework.  This is a new implementation of aggregation operations, written in C++, and tightly integrated into the MongoDB framework.

Most Map/Reduce jobs can be rewritten to use the Aggregation Framework.  They usually run faster (20x speed improvement vs. Map/Reduce is common in version 2.2), they make full use of the existing query engine, and you can run multiple Aggregation commands in parallel.

If you have real-time aggregation requirements, the first place to start is with the Aggregation Framework. For more information about the aggregation framework, take a look at these links:

- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongonyc-2012/new-aggregation-framework
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/

3) There have been significant improvements in Map/Reduce in MongoDB version 2.4.  The SpiderMonkey JavaScript engine has been replaced by the V8 JavaScript engine, and there is no longer a global JavaScript lock, which means that multiple Map/Reduce threads can run concurrently.

The Map/Reduce engine is still considerably slower than the aggregation framework, for two main reasons:

- The JavaScript engine is interpreted, while the Aggregation Framework
  runs compiled C++ code
- The JavaScript engine still requires that every document being examined get converted from BSON to JSON; if you're saving the output in a collection, the result set must then be converted from JSON back to BSON

There are no significant changes in Map/Reduce between 2.4 and 2.6.

I still do not recommend using the Map/Reduce for real-time aggregation in MongoDB version 2.4 or 2.6.

4) If you really need Map/Reduce, you can also look at the Hadoop Adaptor.  There's more information here:

- http://www.10gen.com/presentations/webinar/mongodb-hadoop-taming-elephant-room
- http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/MongoDB%2BHadoop+Connector.html
- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Hadoop+Quick+Start

Comment: The upcoming 2.4 version has another javascript engine (V8) that should improve performance. For details see here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/